# How to use a pd.concat in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

```
x = "'1','2','3','4'"
for i in x.split(","):
      a = (df[df['Column'].str.contains("'"+i+"'")])
      ## I want to write all a values side by side like this.
      ## pd.concat(a,a,a,a,a,a,a,......)
```

Hello everyone!
As you can see, I have a string and I will filter certain columns from the dataframe with the values ​​in this string.

df.str.contains takes a maximum of 6 values, Thus I want to filter separately and collect dataframes at the end.

Therefore i used pd.concat, but i dont remember and couldnt find any way to find typing all the a values.

I need your help.
Thanks in advance,
Best.

Answer (score 1):

you can actually use a list and concat later on:

```
x = "'1','2','3','4'"
results = []
for i in x.split(","):
      a = (df[df['Column'].str.contains("'"+i+"'")])
      results.append(a)

pd.concat(results)
```

This should be faster :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
But it doesnt work. "a" is a DataFrame not a string.

Comment: Hi there, this should work too, you can add DataFrames to a list and then concat them together with `pd.concat`, but I might be missing something here :). Have you had the opportunity to try it? (for reference please look here, https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html `pd.concat` does allow lists of dfs.)